# Application of Hoeffding's inequality on the Stochastic Multi-Armed Bandit Problem

Tags: machine-learning, probability, mathematical-statistics, probability-inequalities

I'm following this [note](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/%7Erebeschi/teaching/AFoL/20/material/lecture15.pdf) to learn about deriving an upper bound of the UCB algorithm on the Stochastic Multi-Armed Bandit Problem. In particular, the proof of Lemma 15.6 there connotes that we can apply Hoeffding's inequality to
$$ Pr(\frac{1}{N_{t,a}}\sum_{s=1}^t Z_{s,a} I_{A_s=a} - \mu_a \geq \epsilon ) $$
where $Z_{s,a}$'s are iid rewards with mean $\mu_a$ and are independent of other rewards, $A_s$ is the action we make at time $s$ which is in general a function of the past rewards and past actions, $N_{t,a}=\sum_{s=1}^t I_{A_s=a}$.

Of course, a natural starting point is to condition on $N_{t,a}=n$, so that inside the probability there are $n$ iid random variables. However, I cannot proceed because $Z$'s are clearly not independent of $N_{t,a}$. (as $N_{t,a}$ depends on $(A_s)_{s=1,...,t}$ and each $A_s$ depends on $(Z_{i,a})_{i=1,...,s-1, a\in A}$; in particular, UCB speficies $A_{s+1}= argmax_a U_{s,a}:= \frac{1}{N_{t,a}}\sum_{s=1}^t Z_{s,a} I_{A_s=a} + \sqrt{\frac{log(s)}{2N_{s,a}}}$)

Similarly, online notes [here](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6783/2021fa/lec25.pdf) (page 2, Lemma 1) and [here](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse599i/18wi/resources/lecture3/lecture3.pdf) (page 8, Theorem 4) all directly claim that we can apply Hoeffding's inequality to the above inequality without justification.

I'm aware that there are other methods to derive an upper bound for UCB, but I'd really like to confirm if this approach is a dead end.

Comment: For UCB, arms are independent and the time series of each arm/action $a$ is also independent. When applying Hoeffding's inequality we get an upper bound probability $p_{s,a} = exp(-2*N_{s,a}*\epsilon^2)$ for each arm/action, if its current average reward is higher than its true mean by $\epsilon$ at time $s$. If we assume $p_{t,a} = s^{-1}$ decreasing as time, we get $\epsilon$ as the second part in the argmax expression.

Comment: It is $p_{s,a} = s^{-1}$, generally, we assume $s^{-\alpha}$